# Bugzilla: Set permissions to make a product readonly for all users

Tags: configuration, permissions, bug-tracking, bugzilla

i am using a single instance of Bugzilla for issue tracking in multiple projects. Some of my projects are restricted to be visible only to a single group of people while other projects have to be ready-only for everybody (even if they do not have a user account in bugzilla). Submitting bugs should always only be possible for authenticated users. Editing bugs is also restricted only to a small group of people and the bug reporter himself.

Does somebody know how i have to set permissions in bugzilla if i want to make a single project read-only for all users (without logging in)? At the moment you can only view bugs if you have logged in.

**Update**
As sereda described "requirelogin" is turned "off". I also have a group corresponding to each product.

For each product i have set the group access to:
*ProductXY: Mandatory/Mandatory, ENTRY*

User are added to the groups by Regex (".*" for all users) in the group properties.

But when i try to open a bug as anonymous user bugzilla says "You are not authorized to access bug #8. To see this bug, you must first log in to an account with the appropriate permissions."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all projects readable anonymously by default by setting "requirelogin" to off in Adminitration | Parameters | User Authentication. Then you would need to check if those products that you don't want to be publicly visible have correct group security (I think it should be mandatory/mandatory setting for a group corresponding to each product).

**Update**

I believe that for a bug to be visible to an anonymous user, it must not belong to any group. Since all your products have 'mandatory' settings, all product bugs belong to corresponding product group, and so not ever visible to anonymous.

I'd suggest to change group controls for public products to "Shown/NA", and then mass update all bugs and remove them from all groups.

Comment: Updated my original post. Seems like it has to be another permission.